# How to open multiple modals in panel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have 2 modals with the same id into bootstrap panel, in the first tab when I  click on 'send message' button it works well, but doesn't work in second tab.

So my question is: How to open the first element of multiple bootstrap modals with the same id in bootstrap panel?

JQUERY:

```
var session_user_id = 1;

//Open message modal
function message_modal(type_id){

   //If not loggedin redirect to login page
   if(!session_user_id){

      window.location.href = base_url+"users/login";
      return;
   }

   //We refresh the div to show message modal 
   $(".message-modal-"+type_id).load(location.href+" .message-modal-"+type_id+">*", function () {

     $(".message-modal-"+type_id).modal('show');

   });
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3b0sx9ag/)

Comment: why not two different ids?

Comment: @ErcanPeker Because the modal's id is the user id of the member and member can displays more than once in the page.

Comment: Why do you have two modals? They are the same as far as I can tell. Just use 1 modal for one feature. You can have a "Chat Modal" and a "login modal" and an "edit profile" modal, but you only need 1 of each. Different buttons can call the same modal, that's ok.